# Detect if 2 HTML fragments have identical hierarchical structure

Tags: python, html, xml, lxml

An example of fragments that have identical hierarchical structure:

```
(1)
<div>
  <span>It's a message</span>
</div>

(2)
<div>
  <span class='bold'>This is a new text</span>
</div>
```

An example of fragments that have different structure:

```
(1)
<div>
  <span><b>It's a message</b></span>
</div>

(2)
<div>
  <span>This is a new text</span>
</div>
```

So, fragments with a similar structure correspond to one hierarchical tree (the same tag names, the same hierarchical structure).

How can I detect if 2 elements (html fragments) have the same structure simply with lxml?

I have a function that does not work properly for some more difficult case (than the example):

```
def _is_equal( el1, el2 ):      
    # input: 2 elements with possible equal structure and tag names
    # e.g. root = lxml.html.fromstring( buf )
    # el1 = root[ 0 ]
    # el2 = root[ 1 ]
    # move from top to bottom, compare elements
    result = False  

    if el1.tag == el2.tag:
        # has no children
        if len( el1 ) == len( el2 ):
            if len( el1 ) == 0:             
                return True
            else:
                # iterate one of them, for example el1
                i = 0
                for child1 in el1:
                    child2 = el2[ i ]
                    is_equal2 = _is_equal( child1, child2 )
                    if not is_equal2:
                        return False
                return True                     
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

The code fails to detect that 2 divs with class='tovar2' have an identical structure:

```
<body>


    <div class="tovar2">
        <h2 class="new">
            <a href="http://modnyedeti-krsk.ru/magazin/product/333193003">
                Куртка  д/д
            </a>
        </h2>
        <ul class="art">
            <li>
                Артикул: <span>1759</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <div class="wrap" style="width:180px;"> 
                <div class="new">
                    <img src="shop_files/new-t.png" alt="">
                </div>     
                <a class="highslide" href="http://modnyedeti-krsk.ru/d/459730/d/820.jpg" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"> 
                    <img src="shop_files/fr_5.gif" style="background:url(/d/459730/d/548470803_5.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat scroll;" alt="Куртка  д/д" height="160" width="180"> 
                </a>     
            </div>
        </div>

        <form action="" onsubmit="return addProductForm(17094601,333193003,3150.00,this,false);">
            <ul class="bott ">
                <li class="price">Цена:<br>
                    <span>
                        <b>
                            3 150
                        </b> руб.
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="amount">Кол-во:<br><input class="number" onclick="this.select()" value="1" name="product_amount" type="text">
                </li>
                <li class="buy"><input value="" type="submit">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div class="tovar2">
        <h2 class="new">
            <a href="http://modnyedeti-krsk.ru/magazin/product/333124803">Куртка  д/д</a>
        </h2>
        <ul class="art">
            <li>
                Артикул: <span>1759</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <div class="wrap" style="width:180px;"> 
                <div class="new">
                    <img src="shop_files/new-t.png" alt="">
                </div>     
                <a class="highslide" href="http://modnyedeti-krsk.ru/d/459730/d/820.jpg" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"> 
                    <img src="shop_files/fr_5.gif" style="background:url(/d/459730/d/548470803_5.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat scroll;" alt="Куртка  д/д" height="160" width="180"> 
                </a>      
            </div>
        </div>      

        <form action="" onsubmit="return addProductForm(17094601,333124803,3150.00,this,false);">
            <ul class="bott ">
                <li class="price">Цена:<br>
                    <span>
                        <b>3 150</b> руб.
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="amount">Кол-во:<br><input class="number" onclick="this.select()" value="1" name="product_amount" type="text">
                </li>
                <li class="buy">
                    <input value="" type="submit">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: @Asad Thank you for your reply. I added 2 fragments when code fails to detect. It's a real website, so, it's more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are complicating things a little, you only need to return `False` at the end when things have been proven to not be `True`.

Two elements are equal when their tags match, their lengths match, and each paired child element is the same.

Python makes testing if all elements in a sequence are `True` really easy with the [`all()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), and by using [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) we can pair up the element children nicely. `all()` will terminate early if any child pair is *not* equal:

```
def _is_equal( el1, el2 ):      
    if el1.tag == el2.tag and len(el1) == len(el2):
        return all(_is_equal(c1, c2) for c1, c2 in zip(el1, el2))

    return False
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me test it please before I approve it.

Comment: @sergzach: there was a small error in the code, corrected (and further simplified). For your sample HTML, it returns `True` for the two contained `<div class="twovar">` elements.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your existing code is failing is that in the case where there is more than one child, i is set wrongly; you assign it to zero and then never increment it, so you compare each of the elements of el1 to the *first* element of el2, rather than to the element of el2 in the  same position as it.

To fix your existing code, just do this:

```
def _is_equal( el1, el2 ):      
    # input: 2 elements with possible equal structure and tag names
    # e.g. root = lxml.html.fromstring( buf )
    # el1 = root[ 0 ]
    # el2 = root[ 1 ]
    # move from top to bottom, compare elements
    result = False  

    if el1.tag == el2.tag:
        # has no children
        if len( el1 ) == len( el2 ):
            if len( el1 ) == 0:             
                return True
            else:
                # iterate one of them, for example el1
                for i, child1 in enumerate(el1):
                    child2 = el2[ i ]
                    is_equal2 = _is_equal( child1, child2 )
                    if not is_equal2:
                        return False
                return True                     
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

However, your existing code can be made much more concise. You're testing three conditions:
1) Tag matches
2) Same number of children
3) All conditions hold for each pair of children

Each of these is a one-line expression in Python. So you can just do the following:

```
def _is_equal(el1, el2):
    return (el1.tag == el2.tag and
            len(el1) == len(el2) and
            all(_is_equal(c1, c2) for c1, c2 in zip(el1, el2)))
```

Note that since `and` short-circuits and `all` returns `False` as soon as any one of the elements it is iterating over does, this will not do any unnecessary extra computation.

Comment: Thank you. Martijn was the first so I approved his answer, +1 for your answer.

Comment: Nice. The zip part can also be `_is_equal(*p) for p in zip...`